# How to properly create ModelForm in django?

Tags: python, django

There is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=511, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/userpics/', blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    about_me = models.TextField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
```

Form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('user_id', )
```

View:

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        form.data['user_id'] = str(request.user.id)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            # commit=False tells Django that "Don't send this to database yet.
            # I have more things I want to do with it."

            profile.user = request.user # Set the user object here
            profile.save() # Now you can send it to DB
        else:
            return render(request, "dashboard/account.html", {"form_profile": form, "form_password": ChangePasswordForm(), 'balance': get_user_balance(request.user)})
```

All I want is simple UpdateProfileForm where User will be able to update their info. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: You could use an update view as @Sayse suggests, but a regular function based view should work as well. You've shown your code, but you haven't said what isn't working. What happens when `request.method == 'GET'`? Your form should exclude the `user` field instead of `user_id`. You don't need `form.data['user_id'] = str(request.user.id)`, because you are excluding the user field from the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off just using an update view

```
class ProfileFormView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/account.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = '#'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Profile.objects.get(self.kwargs['id'])

url(r'^update_profile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', ProfileFormView.as_view(), name="update_profile"),
```

<sub>Django docs are currently down right now.. I will update with a link to documentation when I can</sub>

Your template then just becomes

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Tried your way. Got ProfileFormView is missing a QuerySet. Define ProfileFormView.model, ProfileFormView.queryset, or override ProfileFormView.get_queryset().

Comment: @VassiliyVorobyov - Sorry, was trying to type this from memory,  ([docs are down](https://isitup.org/djangoproject.com)). You can either do as the error suggests and override `get_queryset` or there is also a method called `get_object`. I'll try to update my answer when docs are alive again.. In the mean time you could try setting a breakpoint in either of these methods and seeing what options you have

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll wait!

Comment: @VassiliyVorobyov - I've updated with a `get_object`, again.. this isn't tested but looks correct (needs error handling)